# Foundation 5 text overflow (not respecting the columns)

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I just followed this tutorial to start with Foundation 
( http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/11/how-to-get-started-with-foundation-5/ )
and I have a little problem.

And image would be helpfull to understand my problem : 
[image]

Does someone know what the problem might be and how I can resolve it ?
Maybe I did something wrong while following the tutorial ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add `word-wrap:break-word;` to the containers css. This will break long words to fit in the container.

more info can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

Comment: I opened foundation.css, and added the line to .column, .columns
It works fine now !
Thanks for your answer.
(but it still seems weard to me Foundation doesn't do it by himself)